# Solving equation with 1 variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Have here the following equation:

R = ρ * (l/A)

Need to solve it entering the inputs I have.

For example, if I enter R, ρ and l, it would return me the A.

If I enter ρ, l and A, it would return me R value.

If I enter R, l and A, it would return me ρ value.

Any idea on how could I do that in Python?

If I enter R, ρ and A, it would return me l value.

Comment: Please read [ask]. What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem? For example, can you think of a *mathematical rule* that tells you what `R` is, given the other values? (Hint: you have already written it.) How about, for example, `I`? (Hint: do you remember middle school algebra? If not, you really have a math question, and not a programming question.) If you don't know how to get the input values or output a result from a calculation, then you should follow any basic Python tutorial. If you do know how to do input and output, and the calculation, *what is the problem*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you should write a function with optional params like this:

```
def get_result(r=None, ro=None, i=None, a=None):
  if r is None: return ro * i / a
  if ro is None: return r / i * a
  if i is None: return r / ro * a
  if a is None: return ro * i / r
  return None

a1 = get_result(r=10,ro=20,i=30)
print(a1)  
r1 = get_result(ro=20,i=30,a=40)
print(r1)  
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try:

```
comprim = input(f'Comprimento: ')

resist = input(f'Resistência: ')

resistiv = input(f'Resistividade: ')

area = input('Área: ')

if float(comprim) == 0:

    comprim = (float(area) * float(resist)) / float(resistiv)

    print(comprim)

if float(resist) == 0:

    resist = (float(resistiv) * float(comprim)) / float(area)

    print(resist)

if float(resistiv) == 0:

    resistiv = (float(resist) * float(area)) / float(comprim)

    print(resistiv)

if float(area) == 0:

    area = (float(resistiv) * float(comprim)) / float(resist)

    print(area)
```

Comment: Zero does not mean there is no value. The comparison should be made with None